# Cron job for Postgresql backup is not working

Tags: cron, postgresql, centos7

I have set a cron job to take backup the database every hour.

**/etc/crontab**

```
0 */1 * * * sh /opt/post.sh
```

**/opt/post.sh**

```
pg_dump -U postgres db_name > /home/golp/Desktop/backup.sql
```

For authentication, I am using **.pgpass** file.

```
localhost:5432:db_name:postgres:password
```

Regarding permissions,

```
chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass
chown postgres:postgres /home/golp/Desktop/
```

The cron job seems to run every hour (I checked the log). I find that the backup file created by cron job is empty. I am using *CentOS 7 1503 and Postgresql 9.5*

**NOTE:** When I run `pg_dump -U postgres db_name > /home/golp/Desktop/backup.sql` as root user in terminal, backup is created as expected.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the full path to pg_dump in your script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying the file `/etc/crontab` manually, you need to add entry like the following (for user root):

```
0 * * * * root sh /opt/post.sh
```

You are missing the username `root` to run cron job as. This is needed because this is a global file (not like the per-user files under: `/var/spool/cron/`).

**Edit:** To help diagnosing cron job errors, you can change the cron job line to read:

```
0 * * * * root sh /opt/post.sh >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1
```

This will redirect all stdout and stderr messages to file `/tmp/cron.log` (append mode to not overwrite it each time cron job is run).

Comment: I have tried using `0 * * * * root sh /opt/post.sh` but the backup file is empty again.

Comment: @RajkumarRajendran: I updated my answer. Maybe, you are getting some DB error.